# How I set the scaling on the Mobile like on the Dektop?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, viewport

I have a website. On the desktop it looks good but on the mobile phone of course not. But I don't really want to make the website responsive. Is there a way to adjust the css so that the scalling on the mobile phone is exactly the same as on the desktop? So that you would have to zoom. I also use react for the website.

Comment: Try this in head `<meta name="viewport" content="width=%set-width-here%, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: i dont have a head im using react

Comment: I meant the head of index.html in public folder

Comment: Does not work :c

Comment: Did u try removing it altogether?

Comment: What do you men with "removing". I only add the meta viewport

Comment: Comment the meta tag so it has no effect!

Comment: yes i did. nothing happend

Comment: Can u set up a codesandbox snippet?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-sea-j94px?file=/public/index.html

Comment: I don't think your code is setup properly, can u please check that it works in the sandbox